# Node JS {"type":"Buffer","data":[]}

Tags: node.js

I am making calls to a database through a node JS proxy and sometimes I get back the expected JSON data I am wanting and other times I get `{"type":"Buffer","data":[]}` as a response. I have never seen this response before and cannot find out why I am getting it sporadically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone seeing this in the future, my api was restarting when the request was made which resulted in that response. I fixed the issue with the api being down at the time of the request and the response is working properly now.